# Do Checkpoints work with Unit Tests?

Tags: apex, checkpoint

I can't find documentation on whether I should be expecting my Checkpoints to get hit when running unit tests.

I ask because, as you might conclude, I'm not seeing them show up in the Dev Console after a test run. The checkpoint itself shows up, but none of the instances of the dumps show up.

This [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22060/developer-console-long-running-operation-error-when-opening-checkpoint) hints to the fact that they saw something show up in the Dev Console

But I'm not even getting that far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do. I just tested it with an asynchronous test case.

[image]

The trick here is you need to have an active [TraceFlag](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_traceflag.htm) with the Apex Code logging level set to Finer or Finest. See [Setting Checkpoints in Apex Code](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&language=en_US).

In the developer console you can check this under Debug > Change Log Levels. Make sure the Expriation on the TraceFlag is green and the Apex Code column is set to Finer.

[image: Active TraceFlag with Finer Apex Code logging.]

Comment: Thank you -- I have a Partner Portal case open that's been going on for 3 weeks now and no one on their side could spot that rather silly oversight in configuration (Apex log level). That being said, holy unfriendly feature batman, it honestly is almost easier to do println style debugging than to hope you get all the knobs twisted correctly in order to get a checkpoint to work :-(

Comment: @daveespo I agree that it isn't the easiest thing in the world to get going. It took me a bit of hunting around to figure out why the checkpoints weren't being generated. I suspect it uses the log output to reconstruct the heap state or figure out the trigger point. Feel free to point the partner portal case here :)

Answer (score 1):

In the "Checkpoint" tab in the Developer Console, double click a Checkpoint to enter the Checkpoint Inspector.

via doc:  http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_view_checkpoints.htm&language=en_US

Another option is go to the menu `Debug` --> `Perspective Manager...` and select `Debug` as the Log Perspective.  Clicking various points in the `Execution Log` will have the `Variable` display (on the right) show what values all of your variables had at that moment in the execution.

A third option is to add `System.debug( ... )` statements to your code to perform manual debugging.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about running Unit Tests -- and as you'll see in this screen shot, I already have it setup as documented but still, no Checkpoints appear when clicking the Run Test button http://screencast.com/t/KxjAAzLQ. You have gotten this working with a unit test?

Comment: Try adding a `System.debug(input1);` after where your checkpoint is.  Then after you run the test, open up the debug log and type in `DEBUG` in the filter input box

Comment: You can add more info to the debug method for instance try `System.debug('input1: ' + input1);`

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not what this question is asking. I know how to do old println style debugging. This question is specifically about the checkpoint feature built into the dev console. I will have to downvote the answer for that reason.

Comment: did you read the docs?  they spell out everything you should need to know

Comment: I personally never use Checkpoints because it seems clunky.  I tried them out before I wrote my answer, and they do work, but again hard to use.  The second option I give seems to be the upgrade to Checkpoints and is actually what I think you're looking for.  Try out the Debugging Perspective in the Perspective Manager -- it shows all the variables in action per line of Execution you look at.

Comment: I'm actually using Mavens Mate and it has support for setting Checkpoints and running tests from within. I felt this would be a functional approach to TDD if I could get heap dumps as I was iterating on tests. As for clunky things, the Dev Console ranks up there :-). I opened a Partner Portal case to see if they have a KB article that definitively answers this. Thanks for your time.