# How to change log levels for apex tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, debugging, logging

I am trying to debug my code when running apex tests, but I cannot see my System.debug statements because there are a lot of log entries like

> HEAP_ALLOCATE...
>   SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY...
>   SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT...
>   etc...

and at the end:

> *********** MAXIMUM DEBUG LOG SIZE REACHED ***********

How can I configure it for tests to show only debug messages in developer console?

Comment: Did you see this - https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm

Comment: While some answers have been provided, it's usually far more effective to purposely cause test failures via System.assert than it is to try and debug stuff and read the logs.

Comment: @sfdcfox That kind of depends on how much of the control flow you need to see. If you need more than one data point, it's not that useful of a strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the console, go to `Debug` > `Change Log Levels`. You'll see the following dialog:

[image: Change DebugLevel]

If you want a specific setting for your tests, click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button, and name it something like `Test_Debug`. Usually I specify `NONE` for all levels except `DEBUG` for `ApexCode` and `ERROR` for `System`. Although it seems there is no longer an `ERROR` option for `System`, so you may want to go with `INFO`.

[image: Add DebugLevel]

If you still get truncated logs, set `ApexCode` to `ERROR` as well and log at that specific level:

```
system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Some info');
```

Answer (score 2):

Generically speaking, you need to set the logType in the [DebuggingHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_debuggingheader.htm) to "Debugonly" when running the unit tests. Each platform will have a different means of accomplishing this. For example, the Eclipse Test Runner has a slider you can use, the Developer Console has a menu option, and the Ant Migration Tool has an attribute you specify when running tests. Specifying the correct level should give you your debug statements without too much extra clutter.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to digging through test logs is to set up checkpoints in the developer console. It's a bit more complicated than simply looking for debug statements, but can provide much more information (and doesn't require code changes to look at different parts of the execution state).

See [Do Checkpoints work with Unit Tests?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46172/do-checkpoints-work-with-unit-tests)

You'll need to have an active trace set up on yourself, the Apex log level set to 'finer' or 'finest', and I believe you can only set code checkpoints via opening your target file in the dev console.